# How to connect with Socket.io? in objective c using socket.io in Swift 5

Tags: objective-c, swift, socket.io

I am updating may existing library `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` with swift 5. My previous settings is already working fine. My previous code is in bellow.

```
self.socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc]initWithSocketURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CHAT_SERVICE_URL] config:@{@"log":@NO,@"forcePolling": @YES, @"connectParams": @{}}];
```

And there are in bellow latest code not able to connect.

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: CHAT_SERVICE_URL];
     SocketManager* manager = [[SocketManager alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log": @YES, @"compress": @YES}];
     self.socket = manager.defaultSocket;
     [self.socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
          NSLog(@"socket connected");
     }]; 

[self.socket on:@"currentAmount" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
          double cur = [[data objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

          [[self.socket emitWithAck:@"canUpdate" with:@[@(cur)]] timingOutAfter:0 callback:^(NSArray* data) {
               [self.socket emit:@"update" with:@[@{@"amount": @(cur + 2.50)}]];
          }];

          [ack with:@[@"Got your currentAmount, ", @"dude"]];
     }];

[self.socket connect];
```